# Input ler mais de uma linha da string

Tags: python, regex

Estou com um problema, meu código precisa ler uma string que contém mais de uma linha, no entanto, ele lê a primeira e para, como se quando a linha é pulada, ele interpretasse como um "enter".

```
def depositlist():
deplist = str(input('''Entre com a lista de depósitos: '''))
clear = re.findall(':.+[.)$]', deplist)
print(clear)
```

Eu preciso que ele leia a lista abaixo e separe as linhas referentes aos valores, excluindo a linha em branco e o horário.

```
1) #9ea587 - EXEMPLO DOS SANTOS - 4000,00 BRL - Neon


[4:46] 
2) #1abcd45 - FULANO DA SILVA- 1000,00 BRL - Santander
```

Answer (score 3):

Você poderia criar uma função para realizar a leitura de múltiplas linhas considerando que o processamento será interrompido quando houver mais de um determinado número **N** de quebra de linhas.

Exemplo (para N > 1):

```
def get_input():
    input('''Entre com a lista de depósitos: ''')
    lines = []
    count_line_break = 0
    while True:
        line = input()
        if not line:
            count_line_break = count_line_break + 1
        if count_line_break <= 1:
            lines.append(line)
        else:
            break
    text = '\n'.join(lines)
    return(str(text))
```

E a sua chamada seria assim:

```
deplist = get_input()
```

Adaptado de https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30239092/how-to-get-multiline-input-from-user